# Could not find module in path: 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, codesandbox

I'm trying to use react native navigation in my app, but get odd error. I'm using online platform [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) with [React Native template](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-q4qymyp2l6).

Dependencies:

```
@react-native-material/core 1.3.7
@react-navigation/native 6.1.2
@react-navigation/native-stack 6.9.8
react 17.0.* (17.0.2)
react-dom 17.0.* (17.0.2)
react-native 0.71.1
react-native-safe-area-context 4.5.0
react-native-screens 3.19.0
react-native-web 0.18.* (0.18.12)
react-scripts 3.4.1
```

```js
import React from "react"
import { Text } from "@react-native-material/core"

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack"
/* ^^^ problem line ^^^ */

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

function App() {
  return <Text>Example text</Text>
}

export default App
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform'
relative to '/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/processColor.js'
```

I tried delete and re-add `react-native` dependency as well as recreate the sandbox, but the problem hasn't gone.